# How do I delete Time Machine backups of my Trash?

Tags: macos, time-machine, trash

Time Machine (external hard drive) backed up some files in my Trash folder and I'd like them removed from my backup. I know how to normally remove backed up files from within Time Machine (right click a file and choose `Delete Backup`), but that method is not working for ~/Trash and ~/.trash in the backups.

How do I removed backed up files from the Trash in Time Machine?

Comment: What's that method that you mention and does not work?

Comment: Thecafremo - Perhaps @CyberSkull alludes to the inability in Time Machine to manipulate the invisible Trash folders because the Finder UI is the only mechanism available to the user.

Comment: I told the Finder to show hidden items, but it only shows the restore command for hidden items, delete is not listed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Time Machine shouldn't be backing up the trash folder(s) under normal circumstances.

In any case, you might want to use Terminal command `tmutil delete` command to delete the offending files.

```
tmutil delete /Volumes/DISK/Backups.backupdb/HOST/DATE/Macintosh HD/.Trashes
```

Comment: I forgot `tmutil` even existed. It does report that my trash folder is excluded, though it also is undeniably also backed up.

Comment: So ... does tmutil delete the erroneous Trash folder? Inquiring minds want to know.

Comment: For the ultimate resolution to the problem, see my post. I'm still marking this as the "most correct" answer, as it provides a great deal of utility.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but [Time Machine does not backup the Trash folder](http://pondini.org/TM/11.html) by default. Did you [modify the exclusions property list](http://pondini.org/TM/Works4.html) to include these folders?

Comment: Whoever downvoted, an explanation as to why would be useful. Otherwise, it's just pure ignorance.

Comment: I'll up vote almost any relevant link to pondini on Time Machine, so +1 for me.

Comment: @bmike Thanks - that 74K reputation carries a lot of weight with it :). RIP James Pond - the definitive TM expert in my book.

Comment: @bmike not too get too off topic, are you over at Apple Support Communities as well?

Comment: I did answer a ton of questions on [Apple's Discussions](https://discussions.apple.com/people/Michael%20Bradshaw) before this site spun up and before I worked for Apple. It looks like they've made it much better and often really good content is discovered / uncovered there over here, but I find it much more useful here due to community editing and the standards about not hijacking Q&A.

Comment: @bmike Thanks for the reply... can we continue discussion in [chat]

Answer (score 1):

The fix to the problem is… it fixed itself. Really. Between posting this problem and trying a solution I had disconnected my backup drive and put my laptop to sleep.

When I reconnected the backup drive later to try @icondaemon's solution, it turned out then that I couldn't find the files in the backup. I was very thorough in checking. Moreover, the Finder/Time Machine was now letting me delete backups of dot files and hidden flag files.

So I'm happy now that it's taken care of, but a bit tired and confused since there is no obvious solution.